# WPF - Copying resources on publishing

Tags: wpf

I'm developing an WPF application that has an reference of a C# Class Library.
That C# Class Library has a few XML files that i'm copying to output as embed resources.

When i debug the WPF application, those XML are copied to debug folder of WPF and the app runs properly.
But when i publish the application i get errors because the application isn't finding the resources.

I must admit i'm just now introducing to WPF, so i haven't understand yet the process of publishing and installing the application.

Those XML files should be published by VS in "Aplication Files" folder of the published folder? If yes, what i'm i doing wrong?

By the way, i'm accessing those files in my code (of C# Class Library) from **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using click once for publishing? you can define what dependencies you need and for each one where place must have.